# Вирусы на сервере, как найти дыру?

Tags: безопасность, веб-сервер, вирусы

В логах сайтов вижу записи создания вредоносных файлов на сервере. Я не могу понять, как со стороны создают файлы с вирусами на сервере?

Пример:

```
176.32.230.52 - - [17/May/2018:09:36:57 +0300] "POST /js/validation/localization/gizzakij.php HTTP/1.0" 200 265 "https://site.ru/js/validation/localization/gizzakij.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

Я понимаю, что можно заблокировать через брандмауэр, но хочу разобраться как именно получают доступ на создание файлов на сервере. Доступ у папки 755, смены прав на папку файлы, нечего не дает. Спасает только цементирование через chattr.

В примере выше сайт на Битриксе, но есть и другие CMS Modx, фреймворк CI. Ситуация аналогичная, создаются вирусные файлы. Сканирование Aibolit и сервис Virusdie не помогают. Видят только уже созданные файлы.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/users/176349/

Comment: Может быть абсолютно что угодно, от неприкрытого фтп до обидевшегося на вас админа этих сайтов

Comment: Ответ, чтобы ответить? Я админ сайтов, ftp нет открытых и там менялись пароли.

Comment: Может, *вам кажется*, что там нет ничего открытого? Может, менять пароли бесполезно, потому что злоумышленник давно прописал себе ssh-ключ или вообще создал себе отдельного пользователя? Может, где-то на всех сайтах лежит какой-нибудь нужный, но уязвимый php-скрипт? Может, на сервере устаревшее ПО? Тут, к сожалению, в рамках ruSO трудно ответить что-то внятное, более разумным выглядит полный аудит сервера соответствующим специалистом